# multiple if conditions nested with a concatenate - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula as follows which I'm using for a scheduling system within Google Sheets:

```
=IF(B2="","",(CONCATENATE($B$1&" "&B2&CHAR(10)&$C$1&" "&C2&CHAR(10)&$D$1&" "&D2&CHAR(10)&$E$1&" " &E2&CHAR(10)&$F$1&" " &F2&CHAR(10)&$G$1&" " &G2)))
```

currently my formula works b2 has a value inside it which is great, what I want however, is for the formula *only* to show if one value is inside either.

B2, C2, D2, E2, F2 or G2.

so if c2 has a value I want the formula to parse.

I've tried

```
=IF(B2,C2,E2) etc with no luck.
```

I've also tried:

`=IF(OR(B2="",C2="")` which parsed the formula but kept it visible even with no data.

Reason for this is that I pull these fields into a master schedule and I only want it to show when one of the fields is populated, if that makes sense? otherwise the schedule will look far to busy.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KE3VOI43M4-QlWB0EZldCqR73d3RHDnRnUNlv1MqLMo/edit?usp=sharing

Document for you guys.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `AND()` instead of `OR()`.

```
=IF(AND(B2="", C2=""), "", "Formula")
```

Also, although this makes the formulas longer, I do prefer to use a combination of `IFERROR()`, `ISBLANK()`, and `NA()`. I prefer this because a *blank* cell is not the same as one with an empty string in it. So my preferred way of writing the above would actually be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2), ISBLANK(C2)), NA(), "Formula"))
```

Comment: The IFERROR makes total absoloute sense, but I don't understand the NA() bit? perfect this looks like exactly what I needed.

Comment: `NA()` throws the error, which `IFERROR()` handles by leaving the cell blank instead of putting in a blank string of `""` @Datanovice If it works for you, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to show a formula when any of a given range of cells is not empty (and display nothing if they are all empty), you can simplify your condition check by first joining all ranges, and then comparing to the empty string:

```
=IF(JOIN("", B2:G2)="", "", "Your Formula")
```

Answer (score 0):

just another solution I came across which I thought was much better than my own and made the data above a little tidier.

```
=IF(A2<>"",CONCATENATE(IF(B2<>"",$B$1&": "&B2&CHAR(10),),
                   IF(C2<>"",$C$1&": "&C2&IF(OR(D2<>"",E2<>"",F2<>"",G2<>""),CHAR(10),),),
```

Essentially this will populate only whats selected instead of populating all the fields in headers and then populating the scheduled work stream.